# Simulating Bernoulli sample mean confidence interval in python

Tags: confidence-interval, python, bernoulli-distribution

I'm working through exercises in my statistics textbook, and I'm getting a result I don't understand that I don't know if it's a programming problem or an understanding statistics problem. I'm trying to do the computer experiment part of this problem:

[image: picture of problem from textbook]

The code for my solution follows below. I believe the result that I'm supposed be getting is that the probability of the sample mean being in the interval across many simulations should be $1-\alpha=0.95$. However my plots consistently show 99%. What am I doing wrong? I loop over the different possible sample sizes, and for each possible sample size I perform a number of simulations and compute the sample mean for each simulation. Then I iterate over the samples to check for what fraction of them is $p$ within the interval.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import random
import matplotlib
import math
matplotlib.use("TkAgg") # without this nothing appears?!
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sys

def calculate_bernoulli_sample_mean(n, p):
    # s = sum([(1 if random.uniform(0, 1) <= p else 0) for i in range(n)])
    # print("n:",n," s:",s," s/n:",s/n)
    # return sum([(1 if random.uniform(0, 1) <= p else 0) for i in range(int(n))]) / int(n)
    return np.sum(np.random.binomial(1,p, int(n))) / int(n)

def calculate_epsilon(n, alpha):
    return math.sqrt((1/(2*n))*math.log(2/alpha))

def simulate():
    p = 0.4
    alpha = 0.05
    coverages = []
    sample_sizes = []
    interval_lengths = []
    simulations = 10000
    for sample_size in np.logspace(1, 4):
        print(sample_size)
        samples = [calculate_bernoulli_sample_mean(sample_size, p) for x in range(simulations)]
        epsilon = calculate_epsilon(sample_size, alpha)

        coverage = 0
        for sample in samples:
            # print(sample)
            interval_lower_bound = sample - epsilon
            interval_upper_bound = sample + epsilon
            if interval_lower_bound < p and p < interval_upper_bound:
                coverage += 1

        coverage /= len(samples)
        # print(coverage)
        coverages.append(coverage)
        sample_sizes.append(sample_size)

    plt.plot(sample_sizes, coverages)
    plt.show()

simulate()
```

The resulting plot doesn't seem very enlightening:

[image]

Comment: Hoeffding's bound is just that: a bound, not an equality.  Note the $\geq$ sign in the statement $\mathbb{P}(C_n \text{ contains }p) \geq 1-\alpha$.

Comment: @jbowman sure, but I’d still expect the plot to reveal a relationship — its just a jagged mess between 1 and .99 with no clear effect from sample size. Also part c asks to plot sample size vs interval... but we have many intervals for the same sample size, so I still suspect I’m misinterpreting something.

Comment: Try increasing `simulations` to something larger, like say `10000`, and alter your `sample_size` to not have sample sizes like 9000, 9250, ... but say 1,10,100,1000,10000, or maybe 1,3,10,30,....   You'll get much more precision on the coverage estimates and fewer near-duplicate sample sizes.

Comment: @jbowman: I tried it and updated the code and added the resulting plot to my question -- it's still not clear what I'm supposed to be seeing.

Comment: You're interpreting it just fine: this procedure tends to produce about 99.4% coverage in the cases you are simulating.  (If you were to extend the values of $n$ to much greater values you would see that the plot isn't a "jagged mess" at all.  Indeed, look closely at the labels on the vertical axis: just how much is the coverage actually varying between repeated simulations? Not a lot.)  If you go back and read the question carefully you will see it doesn't claim this is a 95% interval.

Comment: I think what you're supposed to be seeing is that Hoeffding's bound is not very tight.  I tried it in R and got a fairly similar plot.

Comment: @jbowman good point about the labels. If you see the same thing in R I’m satisfied I’m not messing it up. You want to put as an answer so I can mark correct?

Comment: The labels point was actually from @whuber, just to give credit where credit is due.